# Could not create oracle database connection from jboss

Tags: java, oracle, jboss

During my development, server(jboss4.0) was restarted because of some changes in java source and server failed to restart with the below stacktrace.

```
[JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=186647552)(ERR=12514)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12514)(EMFI=4)))))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:565)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:491)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:341)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:301)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=186647552)(ERR=12514)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12514)(EMFI=4))))
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:171)
    ... 150 more
17:51:19,271 WARN  [SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection metadata
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=
```

I have even successfully tested connection with a standalone java program and with ping. Also it is connecting from my oracle sql developer. I'm using oracle 9i.

What could be the reason as its suddenly getting into this error?

Comment: Maybe this link helps... http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm

Comment: As latest update, there was a problem in the databse server and is now resolved. However i'm surprised how its got connected from my standalone application and from sql developer. Anyhow this error is no more!!